# Redux trigger reducer if value not changing

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've got a reducer function like the following:

```
        nextStep: (state) => {
            if (state.currentStep < state.totalSteps && state.currentStepValid) {
                state.currentStep += 1;
            }
        },
```

I'm listening to changes with the "useSelector" hook and I need to trigger a change even if the value doesn't change when dispatch is called. How is it possible to implement this?

Best regards!

Comment: Have u registred ur redurect when u creating store?

Answer (score 1):

At first you must create store and add your reducer to `createStore` method

```
import todoApp from './reducers'

const store = createStore(todoApp)
```

Then implement your reducer as function, which consume two params `prevState` and `actions` and return next state based on action, like this in basic example [Basic tutorial](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers)

```
import { VisibilityFilters } from './actions'

const initialState = {
  visibilityFilter: VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL,
  todos: []
}

function todoApp(state, action) {
  if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
    return initialState
  }

  // For now, don't handle any actions
  // and just return the state given to us.
  return state
}
```

In your code snippet, you aren't returning next state instead you are modify prev state.

You must write something like that:

```
nextStep: (state) => {
            if (state.currentStep < state.totalSteps && state.currentStepValid) {
                return {
                     ...state,
                     currentStep: state.currentStep + 1
                };
            } else {
                return state;
            }
        },
```

Comment: The functionality stillt works. The problem now is that if the else condition fires and just the state is returned it doesn't trigger when I listen with useEffect. For my App I need this behavior. Do you know how I can implement this?

Comment: Yea it's correct behaviour, component is rerendered when state is changed. If u need some specific behaviour, u can implement own equalityFn. Read doc https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates

`const result: any = useSelector(selector: Function, equalityFn?: Function)`